# ViewModel value change handlers code duplication

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have the following ViewModel:

```kotlin
data class Input(
  val email: String = "",
  val password: String = ""
)

class LoginViewModel : ViewModel() {
  private val _input = MutableStateFlow(Input())
  val input = _input.asStateFlow()

  fun onEmailChange(value: String) {
      _input.value = _input.value.copy(email = value)
  }

  fun onPasswordChange(value: String) {
      _input.value = _input.value.copy(password = value)
  }
}
```

I don't like the approach with both `onEmailChange` and `onPasswordChange` as I have to duplicate such piece of code for every property of my `Input` class. I wonder whether I can make it shorter and with no code duplication?

My composable:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun LoginScreen(loginViewModel: LoginViewModel = viewModel()) {
    val input by loginViewModel.input.collectAsState()
    Column {
        TextField(
            label = { Text("Email") },
            value = input.email,
            onValueChange = loginViewModel::onEmailChange,
            singleLine = true
        )
        TextField(
            label = { Text("Password") },
            value = input.password,
            onValueChange = loginViewModel::onPasswordChange,
            singleLine = true
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe there's nothing wrong with this kind of duplication?

Answer (score 0):

You can change it to this:

```
fun onInputChange(
    email: String? = null,
    password: String? = null
) {
    val oldInput = _input.value
    _input.value = oldInput.copy(
        email = email ?: oldInput.email,
        password = password ?: oldInput.password,
    )
}
```